# Window doesnt close from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, popupwindow

I am trying to close a window I seperately opened, but it does not close with the JS command.
Here is the code how I open the window.

```
<td style="width:25px">
    <a href="/includes/delVisa.php?ID=$vid" target="_blank" title="Del"
        onclick="window.open('/includes/delVisa.php?ID=$vid', '',  'width=800,height=650,resizable,scrollbars,menubar'); return false;">
    <img src="./images/delete.png" alt="del" />
    </a>
</td>
```

This opens a seperate window where the user has to confirm the deletion by pressing another button.

```
<form  name="Visa" action="../action.php?action=del_visa&ID=$ID" method="post" >
```

I have tried to put the `onSubmit=\"window.close();"` aswell in there but the button click does not close the window, nor does the user get a refresh on the originating page, which I want to do as well, so the table is "cleaned".

The code which is running from the button in the form field is the following:

```
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
if ($action == 'del_visa') {
    $SQL = "DELETE FROM t_Visa WHERE ID=$ID;";
}

echo '<script  language="javascript">window.close();</script>';
mywrite($SQL);

if ($action == 'del_visa') {
    goback("index.php?site=Visa&OrderBy=fach_nr");
}
```

What happens is that the deletion works, and the popup window gets a redirect to the index site for the visa. But I want to have the popup closed and a redirect with refresh on the main window.

Comment: try `onsubmit="self.close();"`

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: `onsubmit="self.close();"` now closes the window but doesnt do the refresh, aswell seems to make my cookie invalid, as I have to log in again if I refresh manually.

nothing to see on the console